# Implementation of hugepage in a toy operating system

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

I'm working on JOS from MIT course [6.828](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2017/index.html), a simplified operating system that resembles [xv6](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html). I try to implement a huge page mechanism for the memory management part, which manipulates memory page of 4MB in size instead of 4KB default. This is a challenge problem as can be seen from instructions of [lab2](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2017/labs/lab2/):

> *Challenge*! We consumed many physical pages to hold the page tables for the KERNBASE mapping. Do a more space-efficient job using the PTE_PS ("Page Size") bit in the page directory entries. This bit was not supported in the original 80386, but is supported on more recent x86 processors. You will therefore have to refer to Volume 3 of the current Intel manuals. Make sure you design the kernel to use this optimization only on processors that support it!

Some memory regions are far less than 4MB, often several times of 4KB, such as user-mode exception stack, so we have to work with a mix of normal pages and huge pages.

There's not much information in the instruction compared to the potential amount of work to be done. I'm wondering what's the common practice for this functionality in a well-designed kernel.

Let me first state what I've found out and confused about.

- Currently, at `mem_init()` time, JOS kernel splits all physical memory that is supposed to be free (excluding kernel, IO holes, etc) at 4K granularity (page), and for each page it assigns a `PageInfo` struct so that we end up with a contiguous `PageInfo` array.

  I've decided that the kernel should instead split a certain amount of memory at 4M granularity (huge page), and allocates a contiguous `HugePageInfo` array. Is that the correct way in other kernels? How do I decide the percentage of memory for huge pages?
- The instruction seems to lead me into mapping all memory as huge pages above high address, since other than that I cannot figure out how using only one or two huge pages could save me a lot of page tables. However, since JOS maps all memory above high address (and then map some again in low address when it's needed), that means all my memory should exist as huge pages.

  Could some physical memory be a part of some huge page and meanwhile, be a part of some normal page? That doesn't make sense to me.
- As I could foresee, introducing huge pages in kernel will break up a lot of code and functions I presently have, including these for page directory walking, etc. (JOS uses 2-layer memory addressing: page *directory* and page table, so for a huge page there's no page table level at all.) Is that generally true when other kernels introduced huge pages?

Comment: The physical allocation suite should be, IMO, your starting point. There you should craft the physical directory in such a way to keep track and access to the whole physical pool. There you can modify chunks to get the granularity you are request to allocate from virtual memory allocator that, in turn, will build and manage dynamically the virtual memory directory.  In this way you can break memory chunks from large physical pools and reaggregate physical memory back in large blocks when it is released. This is complex anyway, maybe you want have 2 pools with different granularity which ...

Comment: dimensions are related to the available physical memory based on a arbitrary ratio.

Comment: @Frankie_C Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that instead of splitting memory into pages at init time, I should somehow keep track of free physical memory and _dynamically_ make a page or huge page when needed?

Comment: Yes.  this  should be the most effective approach,  and eventually  even the most complex.  managing unpaged memory pools give a lot of flexibility at cost of complexity. Anyway a balanced ripartition of granularity can do the job, but the tuning of the correct ratio is difficult and shouldn't allow for generalization.  You may experience ineffective memory usage based on allocation requests privileging more or less than 4Mb per chunk.